# What does Raekor's Will set bonus do, to the damage type of Furious Charge?

Tags: diablo-iii, diablo-iii-barbarian

I'm trying to focus my damage type on my barbarian. I have one barbarian focused around Fire Damage, wearing Mage Fist, Cinderswitch and so on - all adding to +Fire Damage% - and this is all fine.

But on this barbarian, I am testing out the Raekor's Will set and the full set bonus gives me "Furious Charge gains the effect of every rune".  And my question is simple really, since the runes of Furious Charge will transform the damage to Fire, Cold, Physical and so on - which is actually in effect?  Or are they all (which would be great I guess, but also doesn't really make sense... :P)

Any idea?

Comment: I have no answer, just to throw an idea: maybe it takes on an element of your currently selected rune, and all other runes provide only the effects? If you have really high +% to Fire damage, it may be pretty easy to test, actually. If, with Fire rune selected, you are getting more than x2,11 damage of other runes (760/360) on average, the damage is indeed Fire.

Comment: @OrcJMR except its different in how they did Vyr according to the patch notes: "Vyr's Amazing Arcana
Will now choose which element to use based on the player's highest +% Elemental Damage type"

Comment: One could test the type on e.g. a giant worm. The type of corpse left behind depends on the type of damage dealing the killing blow.

Answer (score 2):

It will be fire damage.

The only rune that changes furious charge's element is battering ram (turns into fire).  If you look at merciless, stamina, bull rush and dread, they all say 'physical'.  Having all the runes means battering will overwrite the element.

Also note that furious charge is physical by default, so the physical runes don't change the damage back to physical.